# When I select a Country from the listbox1 then second listbox should display states from the selected country

Tags: silverlight-5.0

I am Using MVVM Pattern.

when I select a Country from the listbox1 then second listbox 
will display states from the selected country.

ListBox For Country

```
 <pmControls:pmListBox  x:Name="countryListBox"  Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry,Mode=TwoWay}"  >
                <pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate >
                        <Button  Command="{Binding DataContext.GetAllStatesCommand,ElementName=countryListBox}"  Margin="3" Width="100" Height="25" Content="{Binding Title}" >                                            
                        </Button>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </pmControls:pmListBox>
```

ListBox For State

```
<pmControls:pmListBox x:Name="stateListBox" Grid.Row="1" Margin="3" ItemsSource="{Binding States}">

                    <pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StateTitle}" ></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </pmControls:pmListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </pmControls:pmListBox>
```

In ModelView these are my commands:

command to get all Countries:

```
public void getCountries()
{
    CountryServiceClient client = new CountryServiceClient();
client.GetCountryDetailsCompleted += (clientS, eventE) =>
{
    if (eventE.Error == null)
        {
        foreach (var item in eventE.Result)
        {
         countries.Add(item);
        }
    }
};
client.GetCountryDetailsAsync();
```

}

command to get all states for selected Country:

```
public void ExecutegetAllStatesCommand(EventToCommandArgs args)
{
    selectedState = new States();
    states = new ObservableCollection<States>();
            int cntry_id = this.SelectedCountry.Country_Id;

            StateServiceClient client = new StateServiceClient();
            client.GetStatesCompleted += (clientS, eventE) =>
            {
                if (eventE.Error == null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in eventE.Result)
                    {
                        states.Add(item);

                    }
                }
            };

        client.GetStatesAsync(cntry_id);
        }
```

Here i got the data correctly in my list states but it doesnt appears on Xaml.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that the 'states' are being set correctly in the viewmodel, in that case the problem could be one of the following:

1. I noticed you are binding to 'States' (upper case S) and your code behind sets to 'states' (lower case S).
2. Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the viewmodel and call the propertychanged event handler
3. Try handling the `CollectionChanged` of the `ObservableCollection` that you are adding States to as the propertychanged will not automatically trigger when adding items.

Comment: Actually i forgot to create instance of observableCollection in Constructor of ViewModel.